# groovy escape double quoted $

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have this shell script running in a Jenkins pipeline

```
def planResults = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "cd $it; PLAN=\$(terragrunt plan --terragrunt-source-update | landscape); echo "$PLAN"; CHANGES=$(echo "$PLAN" | tail -2); echo $CHANGES")
```

The issue is when I try to echo the "$PLAN" variables.

Here is the solution that groovy recommends, which works near where PLAN is set at \$(terragrunt, however it does not work for a $ inside double quotes. And I NEED double quotes for this command to work properly.

```
solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value 
expression "${5}" @ line 34, column 148.
ce-update | landscape); echo "$PLAN"; CH
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried escaping the quotes around plan

Comment: Or you could use triple double quotes to delimit your string `"""cd... """`

Answer (score 18):

For double quoted string, Groovy will do interpolation on the string firstly.

Because the `it`, `PLAN` and `CHANGES` are runtime variables of the shell, rather than the variables of Groovy runtime. Groovy can't find the responding value from Groovy variable stack to replace the `$it/PLAN/CHANGS` during interpolation.

So you need to escape all `$` if you use double quote in your case:

```
script: "cd \$it; PLAN=\$(terragrunt plan --terragrunt-source-update | landscape); 
         echo \$PLAN; CHANGES=\$(echo \$PLAN | tail -2); echo \$CHANGES"
```

Or use single quote which not support interpolation:

```
script: 'cd $it; PLAN=$(terragrunt plan --terragrunt-source-update | landscape); 
             echo $PLAN; CHANGES=$(echo $PLAN | tail -2); echo $CHANGES'
```

More detail about Groovy string at [here](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings)

Comment: Please be careful with scripts and Groovy string interpolation. See issues and alternative ways: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#injection-via-interpolation